# Ignoring some file separator symbols when reading from csv file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I'm using some code to read a csv file line by line and identify the strings/values in each column. There should always be 5 columns and the last column is always empty (just because there is a comma at the end of each line in the csv file).
The raw csv data looks like this:

```
abc01.jpg,2729192,a2cbaad5,\Folder1\FolderA\,
abc02.jpg,1729127,b2cbaad4,\Folder1\FolderA\,
abc03.jpg,2759124,c2cbaad3,\Folder1\FolderA\,
abc04.jpg,3726126,d2cbaad2,\Folder2\FolderA,B\,
abc05.jpg,5721122,e2cbaad1,\Folder3\FolderA,B,C\,
```

And the code I'm reading this with looks like this:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
{
    string missingCsvFilePath = rootFolderPath + "\\missing.csv";
    string line;
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = reader.ReadLine()))
    {
       var splitval = line.Split(',');

       if (splitval.Length == 5)
       {
           string filename_csv = splitval[0];
           string crc_csv = splitval[2];
           string filepath_csv = splitval[3];

           Int64 filebytes_csv;
           bool parsed = Int64.TryParse(splitval[1], out filebytes_csv);
           //DO More processing
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error: Line in Csv did not contain 5 sections");
           break;
       }
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that sometimes the 4th column contains commas (see lines 4 and 5 in sample csv data), which are also the column separators in the csv file. However, there is always a \ symbol at the start and end of column 4 so it is safe to ignore commas in strings between \ symbols. I do however require the commas to appear in the string filepath_csv. Can anybody help me achieve this please?

Comment: Instead of circumventing errors in CSV I would suggest to make a better CSV. File names are usually enclosed in double quotation marks (").

Comment: I have no control over the csv file as it comes from somebody else

Comment: @SteveW: Is there any chance you can tell them that their CSV doesn't follow conventions?

Comment: No - its something I have no control over. The problem really is with the folder naming convention rather than their csv generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trim the last comma and use the [overload of `Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) that takes the maximum number of elements to return:

```
string[] parts = csvFilePath.TrimEnd(',')
                            .Split(new[] {','}, 4)

Yields:
----------
abc05.jpg 
5721122 
e2cbaad1 
\Folder3\FolderA,B,C\
```

From MSDN:

> If there are more than count substrings in this instance, the first count minus 1 substrings are returned in the first count minus 1 elements of the return value, and the remaining characters in this instance are returned in the last element of the return value.

Comment: var splitval = line.TrimEnd(',').Split(new[] { ',' }, 4); worked great thanks. I'm not sure how it knows not to separate the final column. Does it get the 1st 3 and then whatever is left is the last column?

Comment: @SteveW Yes - read the documentation from the link in the answer.